# Intent URI to go to favorite contacts

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there an Intent URI that sends you to your phones favorite contacts?

Just like *content://contacts/people/* sends you to all your contacts and *tel:* sends you to your dialer.

EDIT

And is there also a way to go to your call log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Favorites:

```
// "com.android.contacts.action.LIST_STARRED"
Intent intent = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.UI.LIST_STARRED_ACTION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Call log:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The favorites class Contacts.Intents... is deprecated since API 5, do you know how to do this for API 5+

Comment: The constants don't exist in a non-deprecated state for API 5+. They are in `ContactsContract.Intents.UI` but that class is `@hide` so it's not available in the framework.

Comment: What is the dir for favorites to use in your second option? The 1st option no work on 2.35 but your second answer worked on 2.35. My hope is i can open favorites and contacts with your second answer. Can you give dir's for both contact and favorites for use in your second command??