# How to get a list of favorite contacts with android sdk?

Tags: android

The question is "How to get a list of favorite contacts with android sdk?". Now I am using android v1.5.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Intent URI to go to favorite contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116147/intent-uri-to-go-to-favorite-contacts)

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, "starred=?",
    new String[] {"1"}, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);
int favorite = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED));
```

1 - yes, 
0 - no