# Intent URI to go to Calendar App

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is any URI or action to go to a calendar app loaded in the mobile.

The question is similar to [Intent URI to go to favorite contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116147/intent-uri-to-go-to-favorite-contacts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it :-)

```
Intent mailClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            mailClient.setClassName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
startActivityForResult(mailClient, MAIL_APP);
```

Comment: I think the calendar app is specific for specific phones. You have to see what intent is being launched when you click the Calendar icon from your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard `Intent` for calendar applications, sorry! Different devices and users will have different calendars, no different than different Windows PCs will have different calendars.

Comment: There is a Android specific calendar which comes along with Motorola milestone. Don't we have intent for that?

Comment: @Sana: The authors of that application have not documented an `Intent` designed for third parties to use to launch it.