# How to display built in calendar in android application

Tags: android

Hi guysiam new to android but i got a task to display a calendar in my android application.Here my question is whether android contains built in Calendar ,if it has please post the code to display built in calendar app.

Thanks&Regards
E.N.Krishna

Comment: Are you writing for a phone or a tablet? If it's a tablet,citizen conn's response should help.

Answer (score 1):

In android ICS (4.0) There is a new API to access contents.

To display the calendar app on a date you can do like this:

```
            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

            Uri uriCalendar = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/time/" + String.valueOf(today.getTimeInMillis()));
            Intent intentCalendar = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uriCalendar);

            //Use the native calendar app to view the date
            startActivity(intentCalendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CalendarView?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch the Calendar that is included by google... have a gander here for the intent you'd use.

[Intent URI to go to Calendar App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453246/intent-uri-to-go-to-calendar-app)